# Convert address in two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have an address in column `iad_Line1 = 415 W 10th St S` and want to split the `415` to column `ad_housenumber` and `'W 10th St S'` to column `iad_street`.

Is this possible in SQL as a mass update for multiple rows?

Comment: Let me further clarify, the full address is '415 W 10th St S' and need to split the '415' and 'W 10th St S' into separate columns as an update

Comment: is certainly possible, what your logic for determining the first and second part of the address?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean

Comment: And i tried something like:

Comment: select 
    SUBSTRING(name, 1, CHARINDEX('_', name) - 1) as firstname , 
    SUBSTRING(name, CHARINDEX('_', name) + 1, LEN(name)) as lastname 
from emp

Comment: What i am asking is, how would you identify that `415` in that address string is line 1. Will you base it on if its numeric or X character count or space index etc? Based on your data, whats the rough approach you have in mind?

Comment: are you want first substring before first space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

```
DECLARE @ADDRESS AS NVARCHAR(50)

SET @ADDRESS = '415 W 10th St S'

SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(@ADDRESS, 0, charindex(' ',@address) ) as ad_housenumber ,
    RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@ADDRESS, charindex(' ',@address)+1,LEN(@ADDRESS) - 3)) AS iad_street
```

**Updated answer with update statement:**

```
declare @source table(iad_Line1 varchar(50), ad_housenumber varchar(50), iad_street varchar(50))

insert into @source values('415 W 10th St S',null,null)

update @source
set ad_housenumber = SUBSTRING(iad_Line1, 0, charindex(' ',iad_Line1) ) 
,iad_street = RTRIM(SUBSTRING(iad_Line1, charindex(' ',iad_Line1)+1,LEN(iad_Line1) - 3))
from
@source

select * from @source
```

Comment: Hey thanks, this works, but how would I update the entire column 'iad_Line1' to split just as the single row

Comment: And this is a view of the result, how do I update/execute this?

Comment: the columns are in same table or in another table. check the updated answer

Comment: columns are in same table, yes

Comment: is this help you... check it out.

Comment: It works for the row yes, is there a way to affect the entire column?

Comment: means? above statement already affect the entire column. what else..pl. give example.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
  (
     AlphaColumn VARCHAR(30),
     DOORNO      INT,
     ADDRESS1    VARCHAR(30)
  )

INSERT INTO @t
            (AlphaColumn)
VALUES      ('415 W 10th St S'),
            ('34 St S'),
            ('415 h St SAVC'),
            ('123 d'),
            ('ww 1')

SELECT *
FROM   @t

UPDATE Y
SET    DOORNO = ( CASE
                    WHEN AlphaStart > 0 THEN LEFT(AlphaColumn, AlphaStart - 1)
                    ELSE AlphaColumn
                  END ),
       ADDRESS1 = ( CASE
                      WHEN noStart > 0 THEN RIGHT(AlphaColumn, LEN(AlphaColumn) + 1 - AlphaStart)
                      ELSE AlphaColumn
                    END )
FROM   (SELECT patindex('%[a-z]%', AlphaColumn) AS [AlphaStart],
               patindex('%[0-9]%', AlphaColumn) AS [noStart],
               AlphaColumn,
               DOORNO,
               ADDRESS1
        FROM   @t)y
WHERE  [AlphaStart] <> 1

SELECT *
FROM   @t
```

Comment: Hey with this, do I need to specify the columns..or?

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are looking for??

```
DECLARE @ADDRESS AS NVARCHAR(50)

SET @ADDRESS = '415 W 10th St S'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@ADDRESS, 1,1) + '-'+ SUBSTRING(@ADDRESS, 2,2) AS ADD1, 
       RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@ADDRESS, 4,LEN(@ADDRESS) - 3)) AS ADD2
```

Comment: Almost, And this is a view of the result, how do I update/execute this? And how would I update the entire column 'iad_Line1' to split just as the single row